# MySql Query with join conditions

Tags: mysql

Let's assume that I want a list of all my books with the author and his country name.
But I only want famous authors or if they are not famous, they must be from country id 123.

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE author.famous = 1 OR (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)
```

This query gives me a list of all the books that have a famous author or from country 123. But I also want the books without an author, so I add "author.id is null or ..."

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE (author.id is null or (author.famous = 1 OR (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)))
```

But here we have a problem, now we have all the books which have a famous author or an author from country 123 AND the books without an author.

But the books that have an author which is not famous and not from country 123 are not in the list. How can I manage this in 1 query? Or is this impossible and do I need a subquery?

I should have join conditions over multiple tables, but that's impossible.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Just to make sure everyone understands the problem. At the end I want a list of **all** my books, and next to the books I want the information of the author but only if the author is famous or if he's from countryid 123.

My queries had a mistake so here is a better query

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE author.id is null OR author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123
```

But with this query I still don't get the books with an non-famous author from outside countryid 123. I want these books in the list without author information next to it.

**So I don't want to join the book with the author when the author is not famous and not from countryid 123!**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a mistake on your first query. Here `author.famous = 1 OR (author.famous = 1 AND country.id = 123)` you're getting only books that their author is famous **AND** from 123. Maybe you meant `author.famous = 1 OR (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)`, but there's no use for this also. Two conditions are enough.

You can just write:

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE (author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123)
```

For the second query, try this:

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE (author.id is null OR author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123)
```

Comment: I had a mistake indeed, I meant author.famous = 1 OR (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123). I changed it. And you are correct about the useless author.famous = 0 check. But still the country is the same and I don't get the books of the non-famous authors from outside country 123

Comment: @Tim are you sure your first query is giving you books of non-famous from 123?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with this query:

```
SELECT book.id, author.name, country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
WHERE author.id is null or author.famous = 1 or (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)
```

Also I changed

```
or (author.famous = 1 AND country.id = 123)
```

to

```
or (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)
```

because of

> or if they are **NOT** famous, they must be from country id 123

Actually it's not much different from your query, I just omitted obsolete parantheses, but I don't see, why it shouldn't work. Are you sure, there are actually books without an author in your database?

Comment: No need for `author.famous = 1 or (author.famous = 0 AND country.id = 123)`... This is enough `(author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123)`

Comment: It *might* not be necessary in this case, still I got used to write queries **safe** and exact to the point.

Comment: I'm guessing it's Boolean, so I see no use for this. But I see your point.

Comment: I've made a mistake over there indeed. I changed my code. But my questions stays the same, I don't get the books with non-famous authors from outside country 123

Comment: I ask again (because it's a quite common mistake here on SO): "Are you sure, there are actually books without an author in your database?" If in doubt, insert one, try the query, delete it again.

Comment: There is a book with an author which is not famous and from outside countryid 123 in my database. So the where clause is false ... and the book is not in my list

Comment: So, you don't want it in your list and you don't have it in your list. And what's the problem?

Comment: No, this is getting complicated :)
I do want all books in my list and i want the author information only when the author is famous or he is from countryid 123

Comment: Maybe it would be best, if you provided sample data and desired output. And maybe you're confusing what a DB does and what has to be done on application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, you get any book with :

```
SELECT book.id, if(author.famous <> 0 or country.id = 123,GROUP_CONCAT(author.*),null), country.name
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = book.authorid
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = author.countryid
```

Thanks

Comment: No I still don't get the books with an non-famous author from another countryid than 123

Comment: but you said this " or if they are not famous, they must be from country id 123."

Comment: Yes, so I want all the books and if there is an author which is famous or from countryid 123, I want his information next to it. Else I only want the book

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an author is famous when author.famous = 1 and not famous when it is 0, your first set of where conditions looks wrong, it looks to currently filter to only famous authors regardless of country, it should be:

```
WHERE author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123
```

If the final data set you are looking for is the combined:

- All books from famous authors (regardless of country)
- All books from country id is 123 (regardless of fame)
- All books without authors (regardless of country)

Your condition would be:

```
WHERE author.famous = 1 OR country.id = 123 OR author.id is null
```